# Make Samsung Portable SSD T3 work on Ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ssd, exfat

When I try to connect the SSD drive on my laptop with Ubuntu Xenial (16.04.1), it refuses to mount it.

It doesn't recognize the exFAT file system.

The error was similar to:

```
Unable to access “Samsung_T3”
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /run/media/todd/Samsung_T3: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/run/media/todd/Samsung_T3"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:
mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to make it work and mount my drive after installing `exfat-utils`.

The command I used:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils
```

Comment: `exfat-fuse` should be enough to mount ExFAT file systems. `exfat-utils` contains tools to create and diagnose ExFAT file systems and recommends the installation of `exfat-fuse`, which is probably how you installed it because Apt installs recommended packages in Ubuntu's default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the following packages worked for me. Old distro.

```
sudo apt-get remove exfat-fuse
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall` does the same thing in one command